# How to consume data from API in Angular4

Tags: angular

I am working in an Angular4 application ,In this I am trying to receive json data in my component file .But I got undefined as response.

Json structure

[image]

Service File

```
 get_New_Products():Observable<Products[]>{
    this.productServiceURL = `http://localhost:abc/api/data/Get_Product`;
    return this.http.get<Products[]>(this.productServiceURL);
  }
```

In service file I got the outcome by using the following line of code

```
console.log(data); //output : Array of data
```

For Specific data

```
console.log(data[0]['PRODUCT_NAME']); // output : iPhone
```

Component File

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_New_Products();
    this.CartdataService.get_New_Products()
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.products_Id = data['PRODUCT_ID'];
        this.product_Name = data['PRODUCT_NAME'];
        this.products_Price = data['PRODUCT_PRICE'];
        this.products_Image=data['PRODUCT_IMAGE']
        this.products_Image_Onhover=data['PRODUCT_IMAGE_ONHOVER']
        console.log(this.product_Name);
      });
   }
```

Here I can't reach the data .I want to bind all the PRODUCT_ID,PRODUCT_NAME..etc in a single variable.I think the way I am trying to get data is wrong.

I must do some magic in these lines ,

```
    this.products_Id = data['PRODUCT_ID'];
    this.product_Name = data['PRODUCT_NAME'];
    this.products_Price = data['PRODUCT_PRICE'];
    this.products_Image=data['PRODUCT_IMAGE']
    this.products_Image_Onhover=data['PRODUCT_IMAGE_ONHOVER']
```

Model File

```
 export interface Products{
   PRODUCT_ID :string[];
   PRODUCT_NAME : string[];
   PRODUCT_PRICE : string[];
   PRODUCT_IMAGE : string[];
   PRODUCT_IMAGE_ONHOVER : string[];
 }
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you provide the whole component code. You might not inject the service correctly.

Comment: Pretty certain you'll have to iterate over your <Products[]>. You did ask an receive an array of them.

Comment: If you are fetching array of json objects you should map to array in component using map function on response array. See post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256658/getting-an-object-array-from-an-angular-service

Comment: @MirkoAcimovic. - that post refers to the old HTTP API. With v4 by now we should assume HttpClient which expects JSON by default now. This is confirmed by the OP in the question - the data was received by the service correctly.

Comment: can you console.log(data) at component side and attach it to the question? @Nikson

Comment: @SuvethanNantha yes it returns an Array of data

Comment: @Nikson I'm asking at component side? did you get array of data at component side as well?

Comment: @SuvethanNantha,yes I can get the data at component side by using console.log(data);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
productData;
this.CartdataService.get_New_Products()
.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.productData=data;
    this.productIds=[];
    for (let item of data) {
       this.productIds.push(data['PRODUCT_ID']);
    }
});
```

If you want to print all the product names follow the code

```
<div *ngFor="let item of productData">
   <span>{{item.PRODUCT_IMAGE}}</span>
   <span>{{item.PRODUCT_NAME}}</span>
   <span>{{item.PRODUCT_PRICE}}</span>
   <span>{{item.PRODUCT_IMAGE}}</span>
   <span>{{item.PRODUCT_IMAGE_ONHOVER}}</span>
</div>
```

I hope this will fix your problem. If you still have any issues let me know.

Comment: can you please help me to fix this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50166996/ngonchanges-not-get-triggered-in-angular4